# Interpolate 3D where z is an array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a grid of x and y values and for each point (x,y), the z value is a 2D array. Is there a way to interpolate along these x and y? I have tried to use numpy's meshgrid but I only understand it enough for a data point in the z direction. x and y points are on a regular grid. All the z values have equal sizes (2 cols and 1500 rows). I hope to interpolate along x and y to get the set of z values for each (x,y) pair. Examples will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: We need further information on the z value. Are all z values of the same size (for instance 5x5)? How do you expect the interpolation to work? Give a minimal example with an input and expected output by **editing** your question.

Comment: `np.meshgrid` just creates `coordinate matrices`.  It doesn't do interpolation.

Comment: Be more specific about your arrays - shape, dtype, etc.  Better yet, create a small example.  Are the x y points on a regular grid, or scattered?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have edited the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Perhaps you could look into [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html). If you want additional, help you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).